# fadeIn() with jQuery

Tags: jquery, fadein

I have a page where I can comment on a specific item (kind ofdetailpage). I want to fade that comment in with jquery. My problem is that everything is fading in. Not only the update I post.

```
request.done(function (msg) {
    if (msg.status == "success") {
        var comment = msg.comment;
        var name = msg.name;
        var update = "<li class='description'>" + comment + "</li><li class='user'>" + name + "</li>";

        $("#bug_list ul").prepend(update);
        $("#bug_list ul li").hide();
        $("#bug_list ul li").fadeIn(update);
        $("#bug_message").val("");
    }
});
```

code on my detailpage:

```
<div id="bug_list">
    <ul id="listupdates">
        <?php if(isset($comment)) $comment->GetAllComments($id); ?></ul>
</div>
```

my function:

```
public function GetAllComments($id) {
    $db = new Db();
    $select = "SELECT * FROM tblcomments WHERE bug_id =".$id." ORDER BY comment_id DESC"; 
    $result = $db - > conn - > query($select);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<li class='description'>".$row["comment_text"]."</li>";
        echo "<li class='user'>".$row['name']."</li>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$("#bug_list ul li:first").hide();
$("#bug_list ul li:first").fadeIn();
```

Comment: thanks. It's working First I did this:  
$("#bug_list ul li").first().hide();
$("#bug_list ul li").fadeIn(update);

So, I forget a first() on the fadeIn.